# Importing a text document into HTML

Tags: html

I was wondering if there is a HTML element that allows you to incorporate a text file into a HTML document - something ala `<pre src="test.txt"\>`?

Comment: Update: actually I only need this for a static HTML document. No serving.

Comment: iframe and javascript already works with static document!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I realize the question is old, but this is for reference for people that later come to this question. I often use the embed tag. It was introduced in HTML5, and isn't ugly like iframes. You will still need to specify width and height, but I suggest doing so with css.

```
<embed src="test.txt">
```

Notice, the embed tag is open ended. The embed tag is supported in all major browsers.

Comment: Is there a way to set the font for the test.txt. I can't manage :-(

Answer (score 3):

Most similar is iframe

```
<iframe src="test.txt" width="100%" height="300">
</iframe>
```

P/S: Most flexible solution is using JavaScript ([How to read from file](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sidebargadfetdevelopment/thread/64ea2d16-7594-400b-8b25-8b3b9a078eab))

Answer (score 3):

as you said, another file is another document, so you'll have to use something that allows you to display inline documents: the `<iframe>` (see [wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inlineframe) for more info)

```
<iframe src="test.txt" height="200" width="200">
  Your Browser doesn't support Frames.
</iframe>
```

if this isn't what you want (frames are... ugly), the other ways to do semething like this is a [server-side include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or load the document into any element with javascript/ajax ([with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/load/), for example).

Comment: This seems to work nicely. Agains, I just need this to generate a static HTML report (iframes are indeed ugly!).

Answer (score 1):

Not standard HTML.

You might thought want to look to see if your server supports [server-side includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) although these are often disabled for being a percieved security risk.

You'd then be able to do:

```
<pre>
<!--#include virtual="text.txt" -->
</pre>
```

In order to get them parsed properly by the server, you may have to give the HTML file a different extension (e.g., .shtml, .shtm) -- this is also specific to a given server's configuration.

Otherwise you'll have to have some dynamic script (CGI, ASP, ASPX, PHP, whatever) to merge the two together serverside.